# Checking if an array is null or empty

Tags: c#

I need to validate if my string arrays are null or empty. Following is my code. Both don't work. Though the array is not initialized with any values, it shows as if it contains values. How can I fix it?

```
string abc[] = new string[3];

first code

if(abc != null)
{

}

second code

if(IsNullOrEmpty(abc))
{

}

public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T[] array)
{
    return array == null || array.Length == 0;
}
```

Comment: your array is neither null nor empty. so your code is working.

Comment: `Though the array is not initialized with any values it shows as if it contains values` where does it show that?

Comment: Did you try with `bool IsNullOrEmpty(string[] array) { return array == null || array.Any(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x)); }`. Array elements may be `null` or `String.Empty` (if this is what you want to check), array itself can be just `null` or 0 length (but not in your code). Feel free to replace `.Any` with `.All` (see MSDN).

Comment: -6 downvotes with 16k views...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This line:

```
string abc[] = new string[3];
```

creates a non-null, non-empty array (it is of size 3 and contains 3 null references).

So of course IsNullOrEmpty() is returning false.

Perhaps you want to also check if the array contains only null references? You could do so like this:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T[] array) where T: class
{
    if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return array.All(item => item == null);
}
```

Comment: To turn this into an extension method, use `IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this T[] array)`